# prove or disprove this problem

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

> **Problem**
> let $\mathrm P$ be the set of prime numbers ;
> $\forall(p,p+2)\in\mathrm P^2: p\times(p+2)=A_1 ,\quad A\in\mathrm N$
> where $A_1$is written on the figure :
> $A_1=a_1^1a_2^1a_3^1....a_{n_0}^1$ where $(a_i^1)_{1\leq i\leq n_0}\subset\mathrm N $
> So we put : $$g(n_0)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{i=n_0}a_i^1=a_1^1..a_{n_0}^1=A_2\quad ,A_2\in\mathrm N$$
> Where $A_2$ is written on the figure :
> $A_2=a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2...a_{n_1}^2,\quad (a_i^2)_{1\leq i\leq n_1} \subset \mathrm N \quad \quad \text{and}\quad  n_1\leq n_0$
> So we find :
> $$g(n_1)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{i=n_1}a_i^2$$
> we reput the step until we finally get :
> $$g(1)=A_k=a_1^k=8 $$ for any $(p,p+2)\in \mathrm P^2$
> **Exemples**:
> $$5\times7=35,\quad g(1)=3+5=8$$
> $$11\times13=143,\quad g(1)=1+4+3=8$$
> $$29\times31=899,\quad g(2)=8+9+9=26\implies g(1)=2+6=8$$
> $$2027\times2029=4204088,\quad g(2)=6+8+5+5+8+3=35\implies g(1)=3+5=8$$
> $$7877\times7879=62062883,\quad g(2)=6+2+6+2+8+8+3=35\implies g(1)=3+5=8$$

I applied these steps to almost all pairs of less than $3000$ and other pairs greater than $5000$ and i did not find any pair of primes refuting this property
I found this problem whill studying one of this articles to prove thet prime dont'end using the topologies in this [article](http://images.math.cnrs.fr/Une-infinite-de-nombres-premiers-d-apres-Furstenberg.html?lang=fr&var_ajax_redir=1#menu)

I wanted to ask if this problem existes before or not because i searched and found nothing about it

So this problem did not exist, how then can I prove or disprove this problem ,even though I did not find any in these results I await  your suggestions and information about this ,thank you

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Ok thank's @Shaun

Comment: $g(1)$ is simply remainder modulo $9$. So the entire question is "Why the remainder modulo $9$ of $pq$ is always $8$ where $p,\,q$ are primes and $q=p+2$?".

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is baffling.  You seem to say $3 \times 5 = A_1$ and $5 \times 7 = A_1$, which both cannot be simultaneously true.  Also, it seems that $A_2$ is the product of a bunch of squares, as you have written it.

Your examples, however make it clear that you intend to take any pair of twin primes, $p, p+2$, then find the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of $p(p+2)$.

Your question is: is that digital root always $8$.  This question is answered affirmatively here: [Digital root of twin prime semiprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335344/digital-root-of-twin-prime-semiprimes) .

Comment: Thank's @Eric Towers

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Alexey Burdin in the comments, the $g(1)=8$ is the same as noting that $A\equiv8\mod9$.  Also, from the definition, $A$ is the product of a pair twin primes.

Let's consider the following possibilities:

1. $A=3\times5$
2. All other pairs of twin primes

In the first case, we get that $g(1)=6$.  This is an exception to your pattern.

For other cases, we can write the pair of twin primes as $6k-1$ and $6k+1$ for some integer $k$.  Their product is therefore $36k^2-1$.  As $k$ is an integer, $36k^2$ is always divisible by 9.  Therefore, $36k^2-1\equiv-1\equiv8\mod9$, and the pattern will hold for all cases except for the pair $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Thank's @Moko 19